# How to get the name of an app when it opens on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to get the name of any Android app when it opens and launch a password window. I have searched everywhere how to find out the name of the app which the user has opened but I have found no working solution yet. I have a service which I'm running on the background, but it only returns my app's name or the home screen name, no matter which app I open.

Here is my service code:

```kotlin
package com.example.applock

import android.app.ActivityManager
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import android.provider.Settings


class BackAppListenerService  : Service() {
    private var isRunning = false
    private var lastApp = ""

    override fun onCreate() {
        println(TAG + "Service onCreate")
        isRunning = true
        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        println(TAG + "Service onStartCommand")

        //Creating new thread for my service
        //Always write your long running tasks in a separate thread, to avoid ANR
        Thread(Runnable { //Your logic that service will perform will be placed here
            //In this example we are just looping and waits for 1000 milliseconds in each loop.

            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                }

                val mActivityManager = this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
                val mPackageName = mActivityManager.runningAppProcesses[0].processName
                println(mPackageName)
            }
        }).start()
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(arg0: Intent): IBinder? {
        println(TAG + "Service onBind")
        return null
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        isRunning = false
        println(TAG + "Service onDestroy")
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "HelloService"
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get packagename? of the app when open? if you get it , it easy to get the name

Comment: I only get the package name for my app and the home screen. If I open any other app the home screen package name is shown

Comment: There an open source app for what you are trying to achieve. Check their code https://github.com/SubhamTyagi/AppLock

Comment: I tried this one, but I needed an app compatible with Android TV devices. It did help me out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have figured it out.
First add this to your manifest.xml under the manifest tag:

```xml
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

**Then go to `apps permissions > Usage Stats` go to your app and enable it.** You can also make a pop up asking for the user to do it once the apps loads.

Now, to get name of the current foreground app:

```kotlin
fun getForegroundApp(): String {
    var currentApp = "NULL"
    // You can delete the if-else statement if you don't care about Android versions
    // lower than 5.0. Just keep the code that is inside the if and delete the one
    // inside the else statement.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val usm = this.getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE) as UsageStatsManager
        val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val appList =
            usm.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 1000, time)
        if (appList != null && appList.size > 0) {
            val mySortedMap: SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> =
                TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>()
            for (usageStats in appList) {
                mySortedMap.put(usageStats.lastTimeUsed, usageStats)
            }
            if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                currentApp = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey())!!.getPackageName()
            }
        }
    } else {
        val am = this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        val tasks = am.runningAppProcesses
        currentApp = tasks[0].processName
    }
    // Get only the app name name
    return currentApp.split(".").last()
}
```

Sometimes the app name isn't the one displayed, for example the "gmail" app has the name "gm" when I tested it. The home screen name also changes from device to device

The logic to call it every few milliseconds to get the current foreground app is simple:

```kotlin
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    //Creating new thread for my service
    //Always write your long running tasks in a separate thread, to avoid ANR
    Thread(Runnable {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }
            val currentApp = getForegroundApp()
            if (currentApp != lastApp) {
                println(currentApp)
                // New app on front
                lastApp = currentApp
                println(currentApp)
                // Do whatever you wan
            }
        }
    }).start()
    return START_STICKY
}
```

And that's it.